# Why Isn't My Model Showing Its Member in View Controller?

Tags: swift, database, model, member

I have a model called Profile with 2 members `posPoints` and `negPoints`. I'm trying to display the points for the current user on a VC called `MyProfileViewController`. When I type `profiles.posPoints` however, Xcode doesn't recognize it and gives me this error

> Value of type '[Profile]' has no member 'posPoints'

```
static func show(for user: User = User.current, completion: @escaping (Profile?) -> Void) {

    let profileRef = Database.database().reference().child("profile").child(user.username)
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("profile").child(user.username).child(profileRef.key ?? "")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let profile = Profile(snapshot: snapshot) else {
            return completion(nil)
        }

        completion(profile)
    })
}

import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase.FIRDataSnapshot

class Profile {

    // MARK - Properties

    var key: String?
    let posPoints: Int
    let negPoints: Int

    init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        guard !snapshot.key.isEmpty else {return nil}
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any]{

            let posPoints = dict["posPoints"] as? Int
            let negPoints = dict["negPoints"] as? Int

            self.key = snapshot.key
            self.posPoints = posPoints ?? 0
            self.negPoints = negPoints ?? 0
        }
        else{
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

(In viewDidLoad of MyProfileViewController)

```
ProfileService.show { [weak self] (profiles) in
        self?.profiles = profiles
    }
    myPointsLabel.text = profiles.posPoints
}
```

*Firebase Database View*

[image: Firebase Database]

Comment: The error indicates that `profiles` is an array of `Profile`, not a single `Profile`.

Comment: How should I fix my code? I just want myPointsLabel.text to be equal to the posPoints for the current user.

Comment: Either access a specific profile in the array or build a string from multiple profiles in the array. It's up to you.

Comment: try with this one
 ProfileService.show { [weak self] (profiles) in
    self?.profiles = profiles
    myPointsLabel.text = profiles.first?.posPoints
    }

Comment: Hi Muhammed. I think that works. How do I convert it to a String though? I get this error "Cannot assign value of type 'Int?' to type 'String?"

Comment: Ideally I'd like to assign this specific int value "profiles.first?.posPoints - profiles.first?.negPoints" to the label text. Also, would using "first?" ensure the current user?

Comment: if let points = profiles.first?.posPoints{
 profiles myPointsLabel.text = "/(points)"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have following issues with your code in `viewDidLoad`.

**1-** Update `myPointsLabel` inside the `completionHandler` where fetching `profiles` is done.

**2-** UI updates should be done on the Main thread.

**3-** First, extract the desired `profile` from the `array` of `profiles`, then access points and convert it to `String`.

Your code should look like this,

```
var profile: Profile?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ProfileService.show { [weak self] (profile) in
        self?.profile = profile

        if let points = profile?.posPoints {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self?.myPointsLabel.text = String(points)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed my ProfileService.show code and posted above. If I use            "self?.profile = profile", I get this error "Cannot assign value of type 'Profile?' to type '[Profile]' " How should I fix it?

Comment: Change `profile` type declaration from `[Profile]` to `Profile`.

Comment: @Aza I made few changes as you updated your question.

Comment: Thank you! I have no errors at the moment, but the label doesn't show the points. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this line `self?.myPointsLabel.text = String(points)` and inspect `points` value.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be running through the DispatchQueue part. Points does have a correct int value.

Comment: So, chances are the `profile` object is `nil`. You need to verify if `profile` is `non-nil`.

Comment: Yes profile is nil. Sorry for the many questions but do you know why that is?

Comment: I never worked with Firebase but i think something is wrong with your child query `let ref = Database.database().reference().child("profile").child(user.username).child(profileRef.key ?? "").
`

Comment: Cool thx you are right. I should just be using let ref = Database.database().reference().child("profile").child(user.username)